# getting response but not getting key value while calling get api in flutter ,some rendering issue till i seached for the same

Tags: api, flutter, get

{success: true}
E/flutter (16591): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (16591): Receiver: null
E/flutter (16591): Tried calling:

Future _onSubmitClick(String ifscdataa) async{

```
//String profile = url+ifscdataa;
final uri = url+ifscdataa;

paramsToken = widget._token;

final headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  //'Authorization': 'Bearer $paramsToken',
  'Authorization': widget._token,
};

print('Bearer $paramsToken');

Response response = await get(
  uri,
  headers: headers,
);
var res = json.decode(response.body);
print(res);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  setState(() {
    bank_name = res['data']['BankName'].toString() ?? "";
    distrcit_name = res['data']['DistrictName'] ?? "";
    branch_name = res['data']['BranchName'] ?? "";
    state_name = res['data']['StateName'] ?? "";

    print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>$distrcit_name');
    print(bank_name);

  });

} else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: res['message'], timeInSecForIos: 3);

} else {
  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: res['message'], timeInSecForIos: 3);
}
```

}

Comment: it is helpful to attach your code along with question

Comment: this is my response from api -{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "BankName": "///// BANK OF ////",
        "StateName": "Rajasthan",
        "DistrictName": "//// city",
        "BranchName": "//// /// ROAD, //// city"
    }
}

Comment: @SriDattaYalla please check i add my code

Comment: @nvoigt no not helpfull in my case

Comment: https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-widget-size-and-position-b0a9ffed9407 this solution relate to my case or not.?

Answer (score 1):

I think error is raising here

```
bank_name = res['data']['BankName'].toString() ?? "";
distrcit_name = res['data']['DistrictName'] ?? "";
branch_name = res['data']['BranchName'] ?? "";
state_name = res['data']['StateName'] ?? "";
```

Instead of accessing res['data'] directly, make a check that does it even exist in the first place

```
bool hasData = res['data']!=null;
if(hasData){
  bank_name = res['data']['BankName'].toString() ?? "";
  distrcit_name = res['data']['DistrictName'] ?? "";
  branch_name = res['data']['BranchName'] ?? "";
  state_name = res['data']['StateName'] ?? "";
}
else{
  bank_name = "";
  distrcit_name = "";
  branch_name = "";
  state_name = "";
}
```

Comment: ok i try this with updated one.

Comment: I've edited the answer, please try that

Comment: ok can you share in detail

Comment: have you tried above answer? now I've edited it match your need.

Comment: Tell me if that solved your issue

Comment: yes i tried its going in else condition.

Comment: tried tthis -  bool hasData = res['data']!=null;
        if(hasData){
         //now assign data
          bank_name = res['data']['BankName'].toString() ?? "";
        distrcit_name = res['data']['DistrictName'] ?? "";
        branch_name = res['data']['BranchName'] ?? "";
        state_name = res['data']['StateName'] ?? "";
        }
        else{
          bank_name = "daTAAA";
          distrcit_name = "null";
          branch_name = "null";
          state_name = "null";
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224140/discussion-between-s-j-and-sridatta-yalla).